# Access Denied in RCurl/xmlParse from R

Tags: r

I'm trying to access XML data from the following URL:

[forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML)

When I open it in browser, I can see the full data:

```
<dwml xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
<head>
<product concise-name="tabular-digital" operational-mode="developmental" srsName="WGS 1984">
<creation-date refresh-frequency="PT1H">2015-07-09T07:15:40-04:00</creation-date>
</product>
<source>
<production-center>Jacksonville, FL</production-center>
<credit>http://www.srh.noaa.gov/jax</credit>
<more-information>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/</more-information>
</source>
</head>
<data>
...
```

However, when I try to download into R, I get the following error:

```
require(XML)
testxml <- xmlParse("forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML")
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML'
```

Using RCurl:

```
require(RCurl)
testurl <- getURL("forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML")
testurl
 "<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don't have permission to access \"http&#58;&#47;&#47;forecast&#46;weather&#46;gov&#47;MapClick&#46;php&#63;\" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;34e722cf&#46;1436445794&#46;3ebde80\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n"
```

I'm assuming the two issues are related. RCurl is working as expected for other websites I tried. I'd like to understand why this is happening in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the XML data from weather.gov using RCurl, by setting the `User-Agent` property in the HTTP header. For example:

```
require(RCurl)
testurl <- getURL("forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=29.803&lon=-82.411&FcstType=digitalDWML", httpheader = c("User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)"))
```

Then `testurl` will contain the same XML that's returned when typing the URL into a web browser.

A list of user-agents for various browsers can be found at http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/ should you need to experiment.

Comment: So we are duping the server into thinking that we are accessing from a browser? Interesting fix. Purely academic, but why would this behaviour exist? Is in a block from the website on programatically accessing data?

Comment: The website itself will have explicitly set restrictions on what can't access its data (e.g., various browsers, IP addresses, etc.) by, for example, modifying the server's `.htaccess` file. An example of why it would block access in this way could be to prevent search bots or engine crawlers from accessing the data, as they wouldn't do much with it except use up lots of bandwidth, which would be expensive for weather.gov.